# I'm having trouble getting the correct return from this function

Tags: c++

I am creating a tic tac toe program. I have different functions for testing different possible outcomes.  When I test my diagonal possibility, it works correctly. However, when I try to test rows or columns it always returns 0. I think it's because my return statement and break statements are in the wrong place ,but I can't find the right place.

```
int testCol (int board[3][3]){//test cols for win
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    for (b = 0; b < 3; b++){
        if (board[0][b] == 1 && board[1][b] == 1 && board[2][b] == 1){//test player 1
             return 1;
             cout << "I work" << endl;
             break;
        }
        else if(board[0][b] == 2 && board[1][b] == 2 && board[2][b] == 2){//test player 2
             return 2;
             break;
        }
        else{//if none are true return no win
             return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no need of break, as that is unreachable code.

Answer (score 1):

Two things; you need to move the `return 0` outside of the loop. Otherwise, you'll never get around to testing all of the possibilities. Second, your output statement is after a `return`, so it's unreachable.

Comment: So I should have no return statements inside the if statements? Instead have a variable inside the if statement. Then once the loop has finished running return that varible?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a `break` statement after `return`. Last return in your function seems to be a false status from function, so you can keep it out of the loop. Your output statement from first `if` branch  should come before your return.

```
int testCol (int board[3][3]){//test cols for win
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    for (b = 0; b < 3; b++){
        if (board[0][b] == 1 && board[1][b] == 1 && board[2][b] == 1){//test player 1

             cout << "I work" << endl;
             return 1;

        }
        else if(board[0][b] == 2 && board[1][b] == 2 && board[2][b] == 2){//test player 2
             return 2;            
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah okay thank you.  I ended up confused on how the return and loop statements interact.

Answer (score 0):

You return early when you found a full column. If there is no winner, you return 0 after you tested all columns.

Here the fixed version.

```
int testCol (int board[3][3]){//test cols for win
    for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++){
        if (board[0][b] == 1 && board[1][b] == 1 && board[2][b] == 1){//test player 1
             return 1;
        }
        else if(board[0][b] == 2 && board[1][b] == 2 && board[2][b] == 2){//test player 2
             return 2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah okay thank you.  I ended up confused on how the return and loop statements interact.